# dplyr filter deletes all the rows

Tags: r, filtering

I'm running a piece of code to filter out the rows based on some values. The command works. But when checking the contents, only the columns are available but there are no rows at all. I want to filter out the entire dataset except those two values

I have written a piece of R code. Also I searched all the possible sources to get the code. There is no error in executing the code. But it deletes all the rows

```
Aq   <- read_excel("mydata.xlsx")
Aqdf <- data.frame(Aq)
Aqdf <- Aqdf[,-c(13,24,25,26,30,33,38,40,42,47,48,49)] #These columns were NA
Aqdf <- Aqdf %>% dplyr::select(everything()) %>% 
dplyr::filter(Aqdf$Staff.category != "Intern (Fixed Term)" & 
Aqdf$Staff.category != "Trainee (Fixed Term)")
```

At the start when reading the data the output is

```r
dim(Aqdf)
[1] 5714   49
```

After removing the NA's the col_size is reduced to 37

```r
[1] 5714   37
```

Now after applying filters,

```r
[1] 0   37
```

I want to know why after applying filters all the rows are deleted?

Comment: can u show a small reproducible example

Comment: We need to see a reproducible example, but are you sure you haven't previously overwritten `Aqdf`? Also a sidenote - why are you using `select(everything())`? You are by default selecting everything.

Comment: With `dplyr` functions, you don't need (and generally shouldn't) the name of the data frame you're operating on, i.e. `Aqdf$Staff.category` should just be `Staff.category` inside your filters

Comment: @akrun I have edited the above code with the sample and also I have mentioned the output of each step

Comment: @camille this worked. I changed it from Aqdf$.category to Staff.category. Thank you